# Android: OnClick shows toast message but crashes when I start another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, cardview

I am trying to call activity by clicking card view. The app is crashing when I click cardview:

Here is the code:

```java
cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   @Override 
   public void onClick(View v) { 
      context.startActivity(new Intent(context,Dummy.class));
   }
});
```

But if I put a toast message instead - it is working fine. What is wrong here?

Comment: here is my code                        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,Dummy.class));

            }
        });

Comment: Add your code by editing you question, also post the stack trace of the crash causing `Exception`.

Comment: It is customary to format code over several lines, to make it more readable, both for yourself and your readers.

Comment: Try to improve code format and title

Comment: your context is activity or application?

Comment: The problem is in the activity, thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **context** from `context.startActivity();`

```java
cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   @Override 
   public void onClick(View v) { 
      startActivity(new Intent(context,Dummy.class));
   }
});
```

If your outer class is some `Activity` subclass it is already a `Context` and it might be beter to use it to show another Activity.